# Why expo sdk 34 makes bigger app size than sdks before it?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am having an issue where after building expo with SDK 34 which is currently the latest release it has a bigger app size than most of the sdks before it

I was using SDK 29 before that which output android app size 19 MB
without any additional things after upgrading app size is 45 MB

I am currently building the app normally using this command

`expo build:android`

also I have tried to make an Android app bundle but it was 47 MB and I used this command

`expo build:android -t app-bundle`

How to lower app size in expo or should I eject ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The higher the `Expo` version, the larger the number of modules for `dependencies`. Your adding of the sauce is not so affected. Two to five megabytes?

It is most desirable that you try to reduce the size of the `app` after turning it into a `stand-alone app`.

To create a stand-alone app and reduce the size of the app, see [this link](https://medium.com/@aswinmohanme/how-i-reduced-the-size-of-my-react-native-app-by-86-27be72bba640).

Answer (score 2):

Refer issue https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/5167
The size increase is due to adding FaceDetector feature in SDK 34.

Not able to make those unused modules optional yet. (answer at 08/2019)